# Can only Extrude or move vertices/edges in a pre-set distance

Tags: modeling, vertices, extrude

I just started using blender yesterday to model a character. I got through most of the head but now, every time I want to move vertices/edges or extrude, I cannot do it properly. If I try, it moves at a pre-set length that I can't seem to get away from. Please help!

You can see the file here (http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=61829621657266848046)

Comment: Sorry for the duplication, I had no idea what this was called..

Answer (score 1):

You've turned on **Transform Snapping** in increment mode.
All transformations will be done in increments determined by the size of the grid.

[image]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit snapping

Please read the **[manual page](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html?highlight=snap#transform-snapping)** for more information on the usage of snapping.

Comment: Thank you so much for information about snapping and helping fix the problem ! I was following a tutorial must have accidentally pressed shift+tab when I actually wanted control+tab. Im still figuring out the hot keys. Anyway thanks!